# Formula to determine the percentage between two numbers based on its opposite

Tags: functions, percentages

I hope this wasn´t asked before, and if it was I wouldn´t know which search terms to use. Hence, my appologies if the answer is already here somewhere.

If I have two numbers, let´s say 2 and 10, and I want to know the percentage of difference between them if starting at 2, it´s 10-2/(2/100) = 400. 
But, if I only know the number 400, and not 2 and 10, is there a way that I can use the number 400 to conclude that the percentage between the two numbers, if starting at 10 so 10-2/(10/100) = 80?
So a formula where I could say:

900 is 90

400 is 80

233 is 70

150 is 60

etc.

I hope you understand my point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I hope you understand my point."* - Not really :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know $x=\frac {b-a}{a}\cdot 100$ but you want to know $y=\frac{b-a}{b}\cdot 100$. As $\frac{x}{100}+1=\frac{b}{a}$ and $y=\frac{x}{\frac{b}{a}}$ you get $y=\frac{x}{\frac{x}{100}+1}$.

Comment: Awesome, haven´t had the need to look at numbers in this way since I went to school, but now it rings a bell and makes fully sense. Thanks user8734617!!! Sorry that I can´t give you any arrow up but it´s my first time on the match stackexchange.

Comment: math even......